# Accessing newrelic API through my application

Tags: java, jboss, newrelic

.I'm using Newrelic for java agent.I install the newrelic.yml file using the command "java -jar newrelic.jar install" in my prompt. When running, it shows the message as INSTALL SUCCESSFUL and some other information. I also find the newrelic.yml setup in running the run.bat file.But i'm not able to see the newrelic API in my browser when running the port as "localhost:8080/newrelic" . I'm started my server in the port 8080.

The log folder in newrelic diectory.My newrelic_agent.log containing the following lines...,

```
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:07 PM NewRelic INFO: Writing to New Relic log file: D:\work\software\jboss-6.0.0.Final\newrelic\logs\newrelic_agent.log
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:09 PM NewRelic INFO: Configured to connect to New Relic at collector.newrelic.com:80
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:09 PM NewRelic INFO: Setting protocol to "http"
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:09 PM NewRelic INFO: Configuration file is D:\work\software\jboss-6.0.0.Final\newrelic\.\newrelic.yml
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:09 PM NewRelic WARN: The apdex_t setting is obsolete and is ignored! Set the apdex_t value for an application in New Relic UI
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:09 PM NewRelic INFO: New Relic Agent v2.3.0 has started
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:09 PM NewRelic INFO: Java version: 1.6.0_12
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:30 PM NewRelic INFO: JVM is shutting down
Feb 8, 2012 05:49:30 PM NewRelic INFO: New Relic Agent has shutdown
```

I'm sure not yet started the newrelic API in my browser.It shows an error as "HTTP 404 the request resource /k12/newrelic is not available.I'm using j.d.k 1.6
Help me please..?

Answer (score 2):

The New Relic Ruby agent has a Developer Mode that lives at the /newrelic path you're trying to reach, but the Java agent does not. Developer Mode would give you a detailed trace of each individual web request your app makes that's similar to what the normal New Relic product does with Transaction Traces.

To use New Relic and report performance data, it looks like you've got everything configured correctly. You should be able to log in to https://rpm.newrelic.com and see what your app is doing.

You mentioned "the newrelic API", but I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly. There is an [API for the Java agent](http://newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-api) that lets you configure the agent. There's also a [New Relic HTTP REST API](http://newrelic.com/docs/docs/getting-started-with-the-new-relic-rest-api) that will let you retrieve data reported by your applications.